# Calculating percentage of column that's a specific string and grouping by another column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

So I have two columns in a dataframe, province & profession. I need to return the % of of entries that are 'teacher' per province (ie it will return the provinces and the percentage rows for the province where profession =="teacher'.) So I know for the grouping for province part it would be using groupby(), and I'm thinking for the percentage that are teachers it would involve value counts, but I can't figure out how to get it as a percentage of entries for that province & not the percent of all teacher entries, grouped by province. I have a feeling that. it's relatively straight forward, but I've been stuck for a while now. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share sample data along with code that you were trying?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information shared, you can try following code to achieve your result:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Profession':['teacher','doctor','teacher','doctor','pilot','carpenter'],'Province':['BC','Vancouver','BC','Vancouver','BC','Vancouver']})
df_grouped = df.groupby(['Province','Profession']).size()
df_grouped.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x/x.sum() * 100)
```